# How to find irradiance of UV LED?

Tags: led, uv

I have a UV LED with the following specifications:

- optical watt: 0.103 W
- beam angle: 15 degrees
- distance from surface: 2.4 cm

Also the circle created at that distance by my calculation is 0.313 cmsq

Is the irradiance 0.103/0.313? I have attached spectral result test if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The steradians work out to 0.0537535 so the area on the sphere at that distance would be about 0.3096 cm sq. Are you assuming the average?

Comment: Beam angle is probably 50% intensity, so not all of the emitted light will hit the surface you e calculated, although probably most will. Consider that an upper bound.

Comment: yes, i'm assuming the average. i dont need to the point value just an approximate

Comment: Your OUTPUT is about 12 mW (depends on actul current used) and NOT the DC input -  see spec sheet.||. Beam angle is 30 degrees, NOT 15. 15 is the 1/2 angle at 50% output - as can be seen from the radiation pattern diagram. || Almost all output occurs inside +/- 15 degres (see areas on inside and outside +/- 15 degrees on diagram). || mW actual / are actual is an OK average estimate. Centre will be higher.

Comment: UV LEDs get a chromaticity diagram on the datasheet? why?

Comment: @Hearth I decided that looked 'rather spurious'. UV LEDs are presumably able to be represented BUT UI'd expect them to be at far lower left (if at all) AND the points shown on the black body line appear to be for standard "white" LEDs. It's not obvious to me that the two datasheet segments are for the same device. I now see where he gets his 103 mW power from (top of first datasheet) BUT this is close to the likely DC input value, and the second datasheet says 12 mW output (which is far more likely).

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense. Irradiance is function of position on surface. It depends on what point on the surface you measure it. To calculate irradiance you need to know angular radiation characteristic of your source.

Comment: i have added a beam pattern, my main question is to find irradiance. the point can be exactly beneath the led

Answer (score 0):

Added:

What does the CI1931 diagram mean in this context?
The points shown on the black body line appear to be for standard "white" LEDs. It's not obvious to me that the two datasheet segments are for the same device.

I now see where you get gets the 103 mW power from (top of first datasheet) BUT this is close to the likely DC input value, and the second datasheet says 12 mW output (which is far more likely).

---

Your OUTPUT is about 12 mW (depends on actual current used) and NOT the DC input -  see spec sheet.

Beam angle is 30 degrees, NOT 15 degrees.
15 degrees is the 1/2 angle at 50% output - as can be seen from the radiation pattern diagram.

Almost all output occurs inside +/- 15 degres (see areas on inside and outside +/- 15 degrees on diagram).

(mW actual / area actual) is an OK average estimate.
Centre will be higher.